# Airflow DAG scheduling

Tags: airflow, job-scheduling, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-scheduler

How can I schedule my Airflow DAG on "Last day of the month"
and on "Last working day of the month"

Note - the scheduling should take care if the month has 28/29/30/31 days and if it is leap year or not.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: According to [crontab.cronhub.io](https://crontab.cronhub.io), last week day can be defined as`LW`. That said, if you want to cover both the last day and last week-day of the month, you should use a crontab expression like `00 08 L,LW * *`. ***Note that***, I did not try this and still not completely sure.

I am not sure how you can define "last working day of the month" but you can define **"last day of the month"** using a *crontab expression* like the following:

```sh
 00 08 L * * # Run at 08.00 AM on the last day of the month, every month
```

### In DAG File:

```py
 with DAG(
     dag_id='tester',
     schedule_interval='00 08 L * *', # Here
     ...
 ) as dag:
        ...
```

#### Additionally,

You can define more than a day using comma, like the following expression:

```sh
 00 08 1,L * * # Run at 08.00 AM on the last day and first day of the month, every month
```

Answer (score 0):

The Airflow schedule interval parameter expects a cron expression. This is well described in the Airflow documentation.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/scheduler.html

Although cron does not explicitly support "the last day of the month" a potential workaround is to have your DAG run as soon as possible on the first day of every month.

For example to have your DAG run at 00:00 on the first day of every month set the schedule interval to:

`0 0 1 * *`